# Parameters of method

Tags: c++, methods, parameters

I have a question about the parameters given to the following constructor:

```
// Codesnippet 1
Foam::argList::argList
372 (
373  int& argc,
374  char**& argv,
375  bool checkArgs,
376  bool checkOpts
377 )
.
.
.
```

1. What does the `&` mean?
2. What does `char**&` mean? In fact I have the code

   ```
   //codesnippet 2
   Foam::argList args(argc, argv);
   ```

where argv is the adress of the commandline arguments given to the main method

```
  // Codesnippet 3
  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Therefore I don't understand why the passed parameter in codesnippet 1 is described as `char**&`.

Comment: Take a step back, and get your hands on a good C++ tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char**&` should be read from right to left. `&`, in this context, means a reference. `*` means a pointer. So this should be read as being a *reference to a pointer to a pointer of char*. Strings are arrays of characters, and, in C and some C++ code, are typed as `char*`. So you can simplify the above to say that `char**&` is a reference to a pointer to a string. If you increment that pointer, you'll get the next string in an array of strings, and the array contains `argc` items.

`char *argv[]` is an *array of pointers to char*. This is another way of saying it's an array of strings, though the use of `[]` makes it a little clearer that it's actually an array.

So you can implicitly cast from `char *argv[]` to `char** argv`. They are the same thing in practice.

As for references (`&`), it's worth reading a proper tutorial on those elsewhere.